# Angular not pulling data through Angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have been having a problem getting data back from the Real time Database on firebase. Everything is set correctly, the Read and Write permissions are public so I don't have to authenticate.

npm compiles successfully. So the code is good (Angular-CLI). I tried exactly what is on the GitHub page as far as the documentation goes.

When I interpolate pulling data from an Object the return on the front end is Null. When I do the same for a List the return is blank. *ngFor won't even work.

Anyone has the same problem or could help?

The code looks like this. That's a direct copy from the documentation.

My database actually has no label that says " Items " as per db.list('items') . I dont think that would be the issue, but would that create a problem?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from      'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
   {{ item | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

The data in firebase has this structure..

```
[ 
 {"THIS" : string , "THAT" : string},
 {"THIS" : string , "THAT" : string}
]
```

That's what the file looks like before I uploaded.

Comment: can you show how your json structure looks like in firebase console?

Comment: Maybe you could try with a different `tableName` instead of `items` just to see if you get some data.

Comment: The JSON looks like this. [ {"something" : string, "someelse" : string}, {"something" : string, "someelse" : string} ].. i uploaded the file to firebase.

Comment: "My database actually has no label that says Items " You need to indicate the name of the node in your firebase database. Can you show it too?

Comment: can you define 'items' as: "items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;" to see if it works? also, why not use "this.items = db.list('items');"

Comment: I cant do either of those because it seems FirebaseListObservable can't be found. What is ppsted is straight forward from the GitHub docs for angularfire2. So i assume since it's been live with no redacts for so long, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to create the `items` collection.

You are subscribed to the `items` collection here:

> `this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();`

Try to import this one and see if you get some results:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "THIS": "test",
      "THAT": "test"
    },
    {
      "THIS": "test",
      "THAT": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

In firebase it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hi tim. I tried that but same thing occurs.. actually its worse... Now the html object that i am running the ngFor on.. totally disappears.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your firebase database?

Comment: Just did. Hopefully you could help.

Comment: Above "0" is the name of the database. All the numbers fall below that. Withing the numbered nest is data. {"This" : "That"} .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2U7w.png

Thanks Tim.

Comment: I modified my answer; can you have a look on it?

Comment: will do as soon as i can, but im honestly under the impression i tried that already. Thogh its the most logical answer.

Comment: I see only numbers in your screenshot, so maybe you can try to create an `items` collection (or post a screenshot of the top of your database)

Comment: test-9712b = Database Name , on my database. The numbers are the same as yours, but minus the "Items".

Comment: It's not working for you because you did not create the `items` collection. You are subscribed to the `items` collection in your code:

`this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges()`

Comment: Thanks Tim. You have been helpful.